What is the significance of the terms "holy," "chosen," and "peculiar people unto Himself above all the nations" in God's plan and purposes?

Are these designations primarily relational, reflecting their role in God's economy, or soteriological, pertaining to salvation?

Do 1 Peter 2:9 and Deuteronomy 14:2 have the same soteriological significance or different ones?


Text: Deut 14:2(NET)

For you are a people holy to the LORD your God; it is you the LORD has
chosen out of all the peoples on earth to be his people, his treasured
possession.


These terms are related and in regard to Israel's calling of being God's chosen nation of priest's to the world.
Exodus 19:6

And ye shall be unto me a kingdom of priests, and an holy nation. These are the words which thou shalt speak unto the children of Israel.

Had Israel accepted Christ as being their Messiah, they (as a nation) would have received the promised kingdom and become that holy nation, but because of their "stumbling" with Christ, Israel must endure their final prophetic seven years of tribulation before Christ returns to establish said kingdom.
Romans 11:11

I say then, Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy.

Romans 15:8

Now I say that Jesus Christ was a minister of the circumcision for the truth of God, to confirm the promises made unto the fathers:


In the Old Testament, the nation of Israel was God’s chosen instrument for witnessing about God’s saving grace.  It was in this sense that Israel became the “chosen nation” (Ex 19:5).  Specifically:

Israel was to be a kingdom of priests to teach all nations (Ex 19:5, 6, Isa 61:6).
Israel was to be a light to the world (Isa 42:6, 49:6, 60:3).
Israel was to be a blessing to all nations via both their spiritual example and teaching, and the promised Messiah (Gen 12:2-3; 18:18; 22:18, Ps 67:1-2, Isa 2:2-4, 55:5, 61:9-11, 66:19-20, Jer 3:17)

Note that while Israel was chosen as the instrument to tell and show the world of God’s saving grace, salvation was always available to all people.  Indeed, the Old Testament contains many examples of foreigners becoming part of Israel, indicating that the Israelite Covenant was open to all and was never exclusive.
The OP specifically asks about the technical terms in 1 Peter 2:9 (which directly quotes the foundation of the covenant people in Ex 19:5, 6)

1 Peter 2:9 - But you are a chosen people, a royal priesthood, a holy
nation, God’s special possessionstrong text, that you may declare the praises of
him who called you out of darkness into his wonderful light.

Note that these designations had an explicitly stated purpose: to, "declare the praises of him who called you out of darkness into his wonderful light."
Let us examine these individually -

"chosen" is an expression that God chose to save His people before they ever sinned, Eph 1:4
"royal priesthood" refers to the fact that Jesus reveals hidden spiritual mysteries about God - a privilege in pagan nations reserved only for the royal priests, but in the Christian church is revealed to all members of God's family, Matt 13:35
"holy" - the word simply means set apart for a special purpose; the purpose here is the unique relationship God's people have to God and their special mission to evangelize the world as per Matt 28:19, 20, 1 Peter 2:9, to, "declare the praises of him who called you out of darkness into his wonderful light."
"peculiar" - as stated above, this naturally follows from all that God's people are - unique!


Are you sure it wasn't exclusive?  Ephesians 2:12
"That at that time ye were without Christ, being aliens from the commonwealth of Israel, and strangers from the covenants of promise, having no hope, and without God in the world:"

Yes - see https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/89583/does-the-statement-all-who-are-led-by-the-spirit-of-god-are-sons-of-god-apply/89585#89585  that verse simply refers to people who have not accepted God's grace by faith

So why did Christ refer to us as Gentile "dogs", and claim on multiple occasions that He had only come for "Israel" while living?

@MarkVestal - if that is literally true then only descendants of Abraham can be saved, which is obviously false.  The truth is on Rom 9-11 where the gentiles are grafted into the tree of Israel to replace the Israelite branches that were pruned off.  Only Israel will be saved but that includes all who have been grafted in.  In the New Jerusalem, those outside are referred to as dogs as well.  Rev 21 & 22.

Descendants of Abraham...by faith (not lineage). Rom 4:12-13 "And the father of circumcision to them who are not of the circumcision only, but who also walk in the steps of that faith of our father Abraham, which he had being yet uncircumcised.
13 For the promise, that he should be the heir of the world, was not to Abraham, or to his seed, through the law, but through the righteousness of faith."  We now have access to the root and fatness of the olive tree, but are not "grafted into Israel".  We are a separate branch of the tree. Rom 11:28 says they are our enemies (concerning the gospel).

Special Significance The plan of salvation was, from the beginning, a redemptive plan for all peoples in all the Earth. In thy Seed shall all the families of the Earth be blessed was what God told Abraham. (Genesis 12:3)
And as such it was predetermined before the foundation of the world that a Lamb would be slain. (Revelation 13:8)
Purpose and PlanBut God needed a race of people through whom He could work in order to bring the Lamb into the world---and bring salvation to all. He chose Abraham (a Gentile) and his lineage whereby the Lamb would come.
And God needed some people through whom He could instruct the world in the ways of holiness and righteousness. He also need a "caretaker" of the prophetic word (prophecies) which would act as signposts to guide the world to  the town of Bethlehem, and the little Lamb born there. (See Matthew 2, "Herod demanded of the scribes where Christ would be born.")
AdjectivesHence we have the words: chosen, holy, peculiar people to describe the Israelites (descendants of Abraham). This tribe was to (a) exhibit God's holiness, (b) record God's Laws, (c) prophesy God's plans, and (d) be as a nation of priests who intercede to God. The Jewish nation with knowledge of the Law, was indeed a "chosen people" to act as a schoolmaster (KJV) to bring us to Christ. (Galatians 3:24)
It must be kept in mind that they were "chosen", not because they were more special than any other race. In fact, from the got go, God informed them that it was NOT because of any of their traits that He chose them (See history laid out in Deuteronomy).
In fact, the long O.T. history of the Israelites portrays an unfaithful, rebellious, idolatrous, immoral, greedy people! The prophets were continually warning them of pending judgment for not exhibiting the righteousness God intended of a people. (See Hosea, Jeremiah 2-3, etc.) Their Law became a curse unto them, (Galatians 2:10). BUT they were still chosen to carry out the redemptive plan for the whole world---the Messiah must needs come to Earth via a human virgin at the right time. (Galatians 4:4)
Brand New CovenantBut, lo and behold, and in spite of the continual wickedness of the Jews, Christ did come and provide salvation to the whole world. (John 3:16) And amazingly, believers and disciples from all nationalities are now called by the same adjectives that the ancient Israelites were known as:

In time past...Gentiles were without Christ, being aliens from the commonwealth of Israel, and strangers from the covenants of promise, having no hope, and without God in the world.But now in Christ Jesus you who were a far off are made near by the blood of Christ...Having abolished...the law of commandments contained in ordinances...that He might reconcile both unto God in one body by the cross...For through Him we both have access by one Spirit unto the Father.Now therefore you are no more strangers and foreigners, but fellowcitizens with the saints, and of the household of God. (Ephesians 2:12-19)


But you are a chosen generation, a royal priesthood, an holy nation, a peculiar people, that you should show forth the praises of Him who has called you out of darkness into His marvelous Light. (1 Peter 2:9)


Unto Him who loved us and washed from our sins in His own blood, and has made us to be a kingdom of priests unto God and his Father... (Revelation 1:5-6)

SoteriologyYes, these adjectives are mainly referring to the Israelites' role in bringing salvation to the whole world---a role that was accomplished in spite of their failings and short-comings! They don't refer to any inherent aristocratic position, nor any special personal fame, nor any racial distinction of note.
And that role of exhibiting God's holiness, demonstrating God's righteousness and love, and of interceding for the lost world, is now carried on by the Church---to whom all the adjectives apply.

For God so loves...the world!

